# How to deal with Pycaret's adding extra features while modelling? (For reusing the model)

Tags: python, data-modeling, prediction, training-data, pycaret

After importing Pycaret I called `setup(mydf, 'mytarget')` and run `compare_models()`. Then, I wanted to save a model from the comparison list and use it on another dataset. What I did was something like: `lr = create_model('lr')`.

However, when I try `lr.predict(mynewdfwithouttarget)` I got the size mismatch error:

> X has 11 features per sample; expecting 37

Other models in the list also output the same (or a similar) error.

So, what is the way to use the models that were trained inside `compare_models()`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create model:

```
lr = create_model('lr')
```

Predict on test / hold-out Sample:

```
predict_model(lr);
```

Finalize Model for Deployment:

```
final_lr = finalize_model(lr)
```

Predict on new data:

```
predictions = predict_model(final_lr, data = mynewdfwithouttarget)
```

Comment: Answer's are great. But for best practices, please provide an explanation. You only posting code makes the OP and future commers copy and paste your answer without understanding the logic behind the answer. Please provide an answer with some explanation. Thank You!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This part `predictions = predict_model(final_lr, data = mynewdfwithouttarget)` seems to be useful. How is it different than  `predictions = predict_model(lr, data = mynewdfwithouttarget)` ?

Comment: Ok, `finalize_model()` tunes the model for the whole dataset including the test data. Source: pycaret.org/finalize-model